# <hr> in coldfusion cfdocument

Tags: html, coldfusion, cfdocument

I am using a hr tag in my cfdocument and it is displaying very thickly like below

[image]

I just want a basic thin line. I tried giving the style as hr{ height:0} but it is not helping. Please advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<p>blah</p>
<hr />
<p>blah</p>
```

Set the border to none, and then set a border-top property:

```
hr { border:0 none; border-top:1px solid #000 }
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GWb9B/)**